# Typescript declare a binding method accessing a constructor parameter get undefined in a class

Tags: typescript

Please see the link example
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAyD2BzRBTATtA3gKG9aaKYAJvAHYgCe0ALmIhAFzQQ1oCWZiA2gLq75g5VmgCuwGvDQAKPPmgA6JXQbMRnHv3wBKLHPw0AFuwgKVMALy16EOQF8B0EEmhWhZCPBAoFzxAoAjTmJpd09vABpoAAMAEkwjEzMbO2YAUgho3WwHIA

I want to have a rest parameter in a class's constructor, I found I cannot do

```
class Logger {

  constructor(
    // A parameter property cannot be declared using a rest parameter.(1317)
    readonly ...tags: string[]
  ) {
    
  }
}
```

So I use below instead, but I then get another error message

```
class Logger {

  readonly tags: string[]

  constructor(
    ...tags: string[]
  ) {
    this.tags = tags
  }

  // Property 'tags' is used before its initialization.(2729)
  log = console.log.bind(console, `${this.tags}: %s`) 
}
```

I look at how it is compiled, I found `this.log = console.log.bind(console,` ${this.tags}: %s`);` is moved into constructor, and before the assignement `this.tags = tags`, that is why it shows the error.

```js
"use strict";
class Logger {
    constructor(...tags) {
        this.log = console.log.bind(console, `${this.tags}: %s`);
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}
```

I thought it should be like this javascript code

```js
class Logger {
  constructor(...tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
  }
  log = console.log.bind(console, `${this.tags}: %s`);
}
```

How can I have a rest parameter in constructor just like above's javascript without errors?

Comment: *"I thought it should be like this javascript code"* but the JS code works exactly like the compiled TS code. In JS `this.log = ...` is also executed **before** `this.tags = tags`. It just doesn't give you an error that you do something silly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear about your intentions here, but one workaround would look like this:

```
class Logger {

    readonly tags: string[]
    log:((...args: any[]) => void) | undefined = undefined;

    constructor(
      ...tags: string[]
    ) {
        this.tags = tags
        this.log = console.log.bind(console, `${this.tags}: %s`)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did thought about that, but then I have declare twice. My class actually have like 10 other methods that binding console.log.

Comment: @Arst then you should reconsider if the rest parameter is worth it.